# SpecFlow. MSTest(VSTest) not finding tests

Tags: mstest, specflow, vstest.console

I have started a new UnitTets project in VS2017 with 2.3 version of specflow. I use MSTest and sometimes VSTest for running tests and was successful in my older projects. I can run my tests from test explorer in this new project. But whenever I use mstest(in VS 2017 Dev Command Prompt) or vstest console, I get the error:

> "No tests to execute."

When I try 2015 VS Dev Command Prompt, I get this error:

> "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

I have exactly same setup as in my other solutions, other than targeted. .NetFramework version, not sure when I need to get it to work.

I tried

1. Downgrading to 2.1.0 specflow.
2. Changing targeted .net version from 4.6.1 to 4.5

Comment: Which unittestprovider is configured in you app.config of the test project?

Comment: <unitTestProvider name="MsTest" />